# Services attempt to bind to IPv6 address before it comes up

Tags: networking, systemd, boot

I have a couple of services on Ubuntu 23.04, BIND and Nginx, which are configured to bind to specific IPv6 addresses. However, they fail to start because systemd attempts to start them before the IPv6 addresses come up via DHCPv6. From my logs I believe the DHCPv6 addresses come up two seconds after DHCPv4.

I can manually restart the services after boot to get them to bind to the IPv6 addresses, but what is the best way to halt their start until IPv6 comes up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux supports an IP_FREEBIND socket option that programs can enable before trying to bind to a specific address. Neither nginx nor BIND support this natively, but `net.ipv6.ip_nonlocal_bind` sysctl can enable this system-wide (which may be slightly risky as it means bind() will never fail even when it *should*).

If you're using systemd-networkd (even if indirectly via netplan), there is a service that you can have in a unit's `After=` whose only purpose is to wait for all network interfaces to be configured. (NetworkManager has a similar one.) Normally you use it through `network-online.target` but it can also be used directly:

- a) Indirectly (the usual way):

  ```
  # systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online
  # systemctl edit named
  [Unit]
  Wants=network-online.target
  After=network-online.target
  ```
- b) Directly:

  ```
  # systemctl edit named
  [Unit]
  Wants=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
  After=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
  ```

Generally though, I'd prefer binding to the wildcard address and using the firewall (nftables) to limit access to the service. (I've already seen – and abused – a system that bound its services to *addresses of* interface A, but did nothing in its firewall to prevent packets from interface B to be routed to those addresses.)

Comment: Thanks, looks like systemd-networkd-wait-online will do the job.

Comment: Incidentally, Nginx and BIND both listen on IPv6 port 443 (HTTPS and DNS-over-HTTPS) so I cant wildcard the address.

Comment: @triatic And while it's fine for TCP, on a multi-homed system UDP + wildcard requires additional features (such as IP_PKTINFO or IP_RECVDSTADDR): nginx (and the DNS server unbound) has IP_PKTINFO support, bind9 doesn't.